# How to overwrite some pairs in java.util.Properties with all pairs from another java.util.Properties?

Tags: java, properties

I'm looking for nice method, to overwrite in Java values in java.util.Properties with all pairs from another java.util.Properties?
Something more nice as this:

```
Properties overrideProperties = createPropertiesFromFile(override);
Properties mixProperties = createPropertiesFromFile(basis);

for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : overrideProperties.entrySet()) {
    mixProperties.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: What about [`putAll(Map)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another approach to override properties

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new FileReader("prop1.properties"));
    System.out.println(properties);
    properties.load(new FileReader("prop2.properties"));
    System.out.println(properties);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) extends [`Hashtable<Object, Object>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html), so you should be able to use the [`Hashtable.putAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29) method to add all entries of `overrideProperties` to `mixProperties`:

```
Properties overrideProperties = createPropertiesFromFile(override);
Properties mixProperties = createPropertiesFromFile(basis);
mixProperties.putAll(overrideProperties);
```

Comment: putAll method need map as parameter. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html , no property.

Comment: @Mark `Properties` implements `Map<Object, Object>`.

Comment: @Mark More precisely, `Hashtable<K, V>` implements `Map<K, V>`, so by extending `Hashtable<Object, Object>`, `Properties` also implements `Map<Object, Object>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to overwrite *only* entries that already exist, but add no new keys that might exist in the overrides, do this:

```
overrideProperties.forEach(mixProperties::putIfAbsent);
```

If you want to write every override entry unconditionally, use this:

```
overrideProperties.forEach(mixProperties::put);
```

---

`Properties` objects are also designed to be chained together at construction time, so in the second case (depending on your application) it might also be appropriate to do something like this:

```
Properties defaults = new Properties();
try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("defaults.properties"))) {
  properties.load(is);
}
Properties custom = new Properties(defaults);
try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("override.properties"))) {
  custom.load(is);
}
```